# How to determine LDPC generator matrix from parity check matrix (802.16e)

Tags: matlab, encoding, error-correction

I have parity check table `H` for 802.16e standard with `1/2` rate and expansion factor `96`:

```
Hb = 
-1 94 73 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 55 83 -1 -1 7 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 27 -1 -1 -1 22 79 9 -1 -1 -1 12 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 24 22 81 -1 33 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
61 -1 47 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 65 25 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 39 -1 -1 -1 84 -1 -1 41 72 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 46 40 -1 82 -1 -1 -1 79 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 95 53 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 14 18 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 11 73 -1 -1 -1 2 -1 -1 47 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 -1
12 -1 -1 -1 83 24 -1 43 -1 -1 -1 51 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 94 -1 59 -1 -1 70 72 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1
-1 -1 7 65 -1 -1 -1 -1 39 49 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0
43 -1 -1 -1 -1 66 -1 41 -1 -1 -1 26 7 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0
```

Then I get `H` in binary form with sizes `1152x2304`: [spy(H) img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq8pr.png)

I want to get a matrix generator `G` from `H`, how can I do it? I need to encode words by multiplying words by a generator matrix (`cw = m*G`, where `m` - input word, `cw` - code word).

I try different ways, but at the end i cant reach `nnz(mod(G*H', 2))` equal `0`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An old question but as I had the same and designed a solution...

This LDPC code is systematic, that is, the code words contain the information bits, and the information bits are the leading bits of the code word. All computations are made in `GF2` (Galois field of size 2).

Let us denote:

- `n` the code word length (and number of columns of `H` and `G`),
- `m` the number of parity bits (and the number of rows of `H`),
- `k=n-m` the number of information bits (and the number of rows of `G`),
- `[A,B]` the matrix formed by concatenating left to right the two sub-matrices `A` and `B` (when `A` and `B` have the same number of rows),
- `A^` the transposed matrix of matrix `A`,
- `Ip` the identity matrix of size `p`,
- `0p` the zero vector of size `p`,
- `inv(A)` the inverse of square matrix `A`.

If `u` is a `k`-bits word to encode (information bits) and `x` the corresponding `n`-bits code word, as the code is systematic with leading information bits, we have:

```
x = u * G
  = u * [Ik,F] = [u,u * F] = [u,c]
c = u * F
```

where `F` is a `k`-rows, `m`-columns matrix. We can also represent the parity check matrix `H` as `H = [A,B]` where `A` is a `m`-rows, `k`-columns matrix and `B` is a `m`-rows, `m`-columns (square) matrix. As a matter of fact, `B` is not singular (it has an inverse). So:

```
H * x^ = [A,B] * x^ = [A,B] * [u,c]^ = A * u^ + B * c^ = 0n^
(H * x^)^ = u * A^ + c * B^ = 0n
(H * x^)^ * inv(B^) = u * A^ * inv(B^) + c = 0n
```

From which it comes (we are in `GF2`):

```
c = u * (A^ * inv(B^))
```

And thus:

```
F = A^ * inv(B^)
G = [Ik,A^ * inv(B^)]
```

An [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) code that computes `G` from `H` (where `H` is already in `GF2`) and checks that `G * H^ = 0` (the Matlab code should be very similar):

```
pkg load communications

function F = make_gen_min(H)
    m = size(H, 1);
    n = size(H, 2);
    k = n - m;
    A = H(1:m, 1:k);
    B = H(1:m, k+1:n);
    F = transpose(A) * inv(transpose(B)); 
endfunction

function G = make_gen(H)
    m = size(H, 1);
    n = size(H, 2);
    k = n - m;
    F = make_gen_min(H);
    G = [gf(eye(k), 2), F];
endfunction

H = [...];

G = make_gen(H);
if(any(G * transpose(H)))
    disp ("Error: G * transpose(H) != 0");
else
    disp ("Note: G * transpose(H) == 0");
endif
```